# Query between two tables to find like records that includes Null values

Tags: ms-access, null, ms-access-2010

I've been having a few problem developing a query in MS Access 2010.  I have not been able to find a solution on the net as of yet but I feel that I'm really close.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. I have two tables that I'm trying to compare and find like items.  Table A is called "DONOTDELETE_FPTable".  Table B is called "Imported".
2. I'm comparing the same columns in both tables.  IP, QID and PORT.
3. My goal is to find like records in the Imported table that occur in the DONOTDELETE_FPTable.
4. I have a Left Join setup from the DONOTDELETE_FPTable to the Import table on all columns mentioned above.

Problem:
I have a situation where a record may have a null value in the column PORT in both tables.  I need the query to return:

1. All matching records between the two tables that have the same data in all columns
2. AND any matching record that has a matching IP, QID and a possible null in the PORT column between the two tables.

Here is the SQL that I have at this point using the "LIKE" criteria.  I removed an data where I'm trying to test for the null since I can't get it to work.  Thanks for the help ahead of time.

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.*
FROM
    DONOTDELETE_FPExcept
    LEFT JOIN Imported
    ON
            (DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.Port = Imported.PORT)
        AND (DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.QID = Imported.QID)
        AND (DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.IP = Imported.IP)
WHERE
        (((Imported.IP) Like [DONOTDELETE_FPExcept].[ip])
    AND ((Imported.qid) Like [DONOTDELETE_FPExcept].[QID])
    AND ((Imported.PORT) Like [DONOTDELETE_FPExcept].[Port]));
```

**Here are the is some example data in the table.IP, QID and Port are the columns:**

**Import Table:**

- Record 1:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 225 / Port: 80
- Record 2:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 111 / Port:
- Record 3:  IP:  10.1.1.5 / QID: 999 / Port: 8080
- Record 4:  IP:  10.1.1.5 / QID: 999 / Port:

Notes:  Record 2 - Blank Port is Null.  Record 3 should not match and not appear in query.

**DONOTDELETE_FPTable**

- Record 1:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 225 / Port: 80
- Record 2:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 111 / Port:

**Expected Results with Query (Matching Records between two tables with Null):**

- Record 1:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 225 / Port: 80
- Record 2:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 111 / Port:

**Actually query result (Issue - Null record is missing)**

- Record 1:  IP:  10.1.1.1 / QID: 225 / Port: 80
- Record 2:  IP:  10.1.1.5 / QID: 999 / Port:

Comment: It would be great if you format the SQL statement properly.

Comment: Sorry about that Luis.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question that I came up with.  After testing different scenarios, I found that I got the expected results from my queries.  Here is the MS Access 2010 query.  Please note that MS Access added the additional punctuation and I believe this was my original issue:

SQL Code as seen in MS Access:

```
SELECT Imported.ip, Imported.qid, Imported.port

FROM

DONOTDELETE_FPExcept 
LEFT JOIN Imported 
ON 
     (DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.QID = Imported.QID) 
     AND (DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.IP = Imported.IP)

WHERE 
     (((Imported.ip)=DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.IP)       And  
     (Imported.qid)=DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.qid)       And
     ((Imported.port)=DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.Port))   Or 
     (((Imported.port) Is Null)                     And 
     ((DONOTDELETE_FPExcept.port) Is Null));
```

Let me know your thoughts.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Will do.  Is there any way I can give you rep points for helping me?  Thanks again and I hope I can help you one day.

Comment: You're welcome, joem.  Please don't worry about points on my behalf.

Answer (score 2):

With the sample data you added to the question, I get the results you asked for with this query in Access 2007:

```sql
SELECT
    d.Record_id AS d_id,
    d.IP,
    d.QID,
    d.Port,
    i.Record_id AS i_id
FROM
    DONOTDELETE_FPExcept AS d
    LEFT JOIN Imported AS i
    ON (d.QID = i.QID) AND (d.IP = i.IP)
WHERE
        d.Port = i.Port
    OR (d.Port Is Null AND i.Port Is Null);
```

If you do not get the expected results with that query, confirm the "blank" `Port` values in both tables are really Null.  If `Port` is a text field, it could contain empty strings, spaces, or non-printing characters ... any of those would be difficult to distinguish from Null by visual examination.  You can run a simple query on each of the tables to check.

```sql
SELECT t.Port, IsNull(t.Port) AS port_is_null
FROM Imported AS t;
```

In results from that query, -1 represents `True` and 0 represents `False`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Let me take a look at this and give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.  I'm still having the problem listed above.  It seems MS Access 2010 adds the superfluous () [] when using their Query design GUI.  I didn't add the extra data.  Your solution above however gave me a few new ideas so I'm going to try something different.

Comment: I made an edit above in my question to include the table data you asked about.  I'm still running into the issue no matter how I slice it.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for all the input.  This has been great help.  Let me play around with this and I'll get back to you.  Have a good night or day depending on where your from.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please notice I just fixed the `IsNull` query, and also removed the `INNER JOIN` suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again Hans.  I ran through a number of test and run into a situation where a specific condition is not being caught.  I will provide some details shortly once I confirm my results.  I did also come up with a solution based on my original post which needs to be tested further.  I couldn't of got to this point without you so thank you.  I will post my testing results in the next day or two once testing is done.

Comment: Hans.  Thanks again for the help.  I ran into a problem after testing the code that you provided.  There is a specific scenario that I included above that should not come up in the Query results that does.  If the import tables has an IP, QID and a Null port field that is does not have a matching recording in the DONOTDELETE_FPExcept table, it still comes up in the query.  I added a record 4 above in my question that should not be in the query results but is.

Comment: Good news is that I learned a few things from your post and came up with a solution that fixed the issue.  I'm posting my solution in the answer area below.  Let me know your thoughts.